# Best tool to create a mock GUI quickly?

Tags: mockup

I'm looking for an application/tool to easily create a mock GUI. This GUI will be used by users to control home devices remotely. They can login to a website or use an application to view/control devices. The GUI should look good, but nothing very fancy. It should have checkboxes, lists, radio buttons etc.

The important thing is that since this is just a mock, it should be quick to prepare. While I am a programmer and know C, Python, I would prefer something where I can just drag and drop elements and make a website GUI rather than code.

The software/tool must be free or very cheap. I thought of Dreamweaver, but it's expensive and I guess I'd need a small learning curve (CSS, HTML..)

What should I choose?

Comment: I use Inkscape for GUI mockups but there are probably better options.

Comment: Depending on what you want, go with pen(cil) & paper.

Comment: there is a software called pencil,  It's available for Linux and Windows, and also for Mac If I'm right. Google for pencil project

Comment: Define 'mock-up'. Nearly any drawing tool will work. It really depends on your particular needs. Also if this is a web UI, it's hard to beat actual HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to just mock up a UI, there are a lot of free / cheap tools, but you will still have to wire up the backend code yourself. Here are a few Bootstrap based examples:

- <s>https://jetstrap.com/demo</s> - link is dead
- http://www.layoutit.com/
- <s>https://www.easel.io/demo</s> - link is dead

You can also try something like [Balsamiq Mockups](http://balsamiq.com/products/mockups/) for just rough prototyping (note that Balsamiq requires paying).

Answer (score 0):

I use Adobe Fireworks(available in CS6 and below). It's very simple(especially if you've used adobe photoshop or illustrator) and, I believe, offers all the components you mention. One downside is that you need to import vector art for very specific elements which might be in other programs; however, this process makes for better designs!

Answer (score 0):

> must be free or very cheap

- Inkscape
- the GIMP
- Paint.NET
- Google Draw
- HTML/CSS/JS
- HTML/CSS/JS frameworks
- Open Office

Answer (score 0):

[Adobe Edge](https://creative.adobe.com/products/reflow) apps are free to try, and after a 30 day trial you might even subscribe. You can also try webflow.com, but that will only let you download the html and css with a paid license, or just go [HTML Kickstart](http://www.99lime.com/elements/) and get in on that not so steep learning curve.
For simple wire-framing I found nothing better than Balsamiq Mockups